# Getting the current time as a decimal point number

Tags: swift, nsdate

I want to be able to get the current time as a decimal point number so it can be used. so for example if the time is 13:46 I want to get it as 13.46

It seems simple but I am struggling getting to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use an `NSDateFormatter` to do exactly this:

```
extension NSDate {
    func currentTime() -> String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH.mm"
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

And now we just use it by calling it on any instance of `NSDate`:

```
let now = NSDate()
print(now.currentTime())
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm a bit confused. I don't want it s an extension and I want it as an int as using a decimal place...

Comment: Integers don't have decimal places.  You don't have to write it as an extension (I don't see why you wouldn't).  This answer tells you everything you need to know, now look at it and figure out how to make it into what you need.

Comment: I have never used extensions before I have no idea where they go? And sorry I meant double, basically as a number and not a string....

Answer (score -2):

you can stringify the time and serch `lastindexOf(":")` and substitue it with a "."

UPDATE
I don't really catch what program language are you using, but it's plenty of library for stringify object so if you have a 13:46 you can convert it to String and, in the same string library you could find the method lastIndexOf(char). But if you don't find it you can always write following this concepts:
String are an array of Char so you can cycle it and convert the char in that position in the char you need.